# Static control with WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style not repainted

Tags: mfc, user-controls, gdi, cwnd

I am trying to create a control that implements the per-pixel alpha blend while painting a 32-bit bitmap.

I extended a CWnd and use static control in the resource editor. I managed to paint the alpha channel correctly but still the static control keep painting the gray background.

I overwrote the OnEraseBkgnd to prevent the control from painting the background but it didn't worked. I finally managed to do it by using WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.

My problem now is that my control is placed over other control. The first time the dialog is painted all works fine...but if I click over the "parent" control (ie the one beneath my control) my control doesn't received the WM_PAINT message. So it is not painted anymore.

If I minimize the aplication and maximized it again the controls are painted again.

Please, can anybody give a hint? I am getting crazy with this control!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have though that if you are processing both the **WM_ERASEBKGND** and the **WM_PAINT** messages then you should have cover all the painting options, without having to resort to using the **WS_EX_TRANSPARENT** style.

Are you sure your code **is not passing** these messages on to the **default processing**?

One other option might be to **subclass** the static control, just to make sure your code is the only one handling these two messages.

Answer (score 2):

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTransparentStatic, CStatic)
    ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CTransparentStatic::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* /*pDC*/)
{
    // Prevent from default background erasing.
    return FALSE;
}

BOOL CTransparentStatic::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    cs.dwExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
    return CStatic::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}

HBRUSH CTransparentStatic::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT /*nCtlColor*/)
{
    pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    return reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
}

void CTransparentStatic::PreSubclassWindow()
{
    CStatic::PreSubclassWindow();

    const LONG_PTR exStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
}
```