# CStatic not receiving WM_CTLCOLOR

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I think I am missing something small here.

I am trying to make a class which inherits from CStatic with a transparent background. I have managed create an instance of the class and it is displayed in the parent `CView`. However when I add a `OnCtlColor` message handler going through the class view on Visual Studio to make the background transparent, it never fires.

Here is a code snippet:

**Foo.h**

```
class Foo: public CStatic
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(Foo)

public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();
    virtual void CreateCtrl(CWnd * Parent, POINT TopLeft, SIZE sz);

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public: 
    afx_msg HBRUSH CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor);
    afx_msg BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);
};
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
void Foo::CreateCtrl(CWnd * Parent, POINT TopLeft, SIZE sz)
{
    CRect Rect(TopLeft, sz);
    Create(pItem->Value->GetBuffer(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER | SS_NOTIFY, Rect, Parent);
    ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Foo, CStatic) 
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
    ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

HBRUSH Foo::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
}

BOOL Foo::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WM_CTLCOLOR` is sent to the parent window, not to the static control.

To catch the message in the static control class, you need to use `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT` in your message map, see [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and use `HBRUSH Foo::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor)`.

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to get a `HBRUSH Foo::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor)` going now. Maybe this should be a different questions but when I use the same as what I have in my `OnCtlColor` method the CStatic remains the same, it doesn't have a transparent background. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: From this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4454240/1850797): you also need to override `OnEraseBkgnd()` in your static class and `return FALSE` to prevent default background erasing

Comment: I have overriden `OnEraseBkgnd()` as per my edit but the background is still white.

Comment: Your .h file contains the old code (`OnCtlColor`), but that was probably just a oversight -- using the same code, my static control doesn't show the grey rectangle any more, just the same white background of the View; try adding `TRACE` statements or breakpoints to see if the functions are called?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update the .h file. Both of the methods are executed: I put break points on them and they were hit. I am painting my views background on the `OnDraw` method. Could it possibly be a sequencing problem. Could the View maybe be painting its background after the CStatic has been painted, or something like that?

Comment: It is working now: I changed when I loaded the CStatic now it is working correctly and is transparent, thanks for all your help!