# How to size to content a CStatic control programmatically

Tags: mfc

I have a Dialog box where I show a record from database.
I want the CStatic fields to size to content.

How can I do this.

I am getting a black space at the end of static field. Here is the image attached.

I don't want the black space in my field.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a problem with clip children flag, or it's overriding erase background or background brush, but it's not done right. It would be easier to fix it than to resize it as quick fix. If need quick fix, then just add blank spaces to 2035. If you need to resize, start with `GetTextExtent()`, `SetWindowPos()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size to content is not the best way to solve this, you would be better off deriving a class from `CStatic` and make it transparent by:

- overriding WM_CTLCOLOR
- overriding WM_ERASEBKGND()

and use this class instead of `CStatic` for these fields.
See [this SO question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18204030/1850797) for more details.

Comment: Perect code available in the link to make the background transparent.
Please check the code in the link by Edward.
Thanks Edward, that worked like a charm.